# geting values form jtable to calculate it

Tags: java, swing

I have a project and it is shopping cart. In the checkout I have a jTable, I want to take the amount and price and multiple them. I tried to put them in variables but I failed.

This is my code:

```
      private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      // TODO add your handling code here:

      try{

        query="SELECT productName,size,amount,price FROM Checkout where cphone="+jTextField1.getText();
        rs=stm.executeQuery(query);
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
         jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(1),i,0);
         jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(2),i,1);
         jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(3),i,2);
         jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(4),i,3);
                 i++;

        }
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: `geting values form jtable` you are not getting values from jtable here ..more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel to do the calculation whenever you update the data in one of the columns.

The code might be something like:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    super.setValueAt(value, row, column);

    if (column == 1 || column == 2)
    {
        TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
        int quantity = ((Integer)model.getValueAt(row, 1)).intValue();
        double price = ((Double)model.getValueAt(row, 2)).doubleValue();
        Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
        model.setValueAt(value, row, 3);
    }
}
```